# GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo for the 2013 Rest API

Tags: permissions, 2013, rest

Does anyone know if there is a client-side (preferably REST) equivalent to SPSecurableObject.GetUserEffectivePermissionInfo(username)??

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question. If yes, can you please post an answer. Thanks.